# separating onclick on elements generated on foreach loop asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make an application where ppl can give in watches for repair. Each order can have multiple repairs needed to be done on the watch (battery, band.. etc.).

In the details view of the order I generate all repairs through a foreach loop with a checkbox appearing next to each repair to mark the repair as done and then the status is updated and I hide the checkbox through jquery.

The problem is that when I click any checkbox only the first repair that is generated from foreach is marked as done in the database but all the checkboxes are hidden.

Here is the view..

```
h2>Details</h2>
<div>
<span>@Model.Customer.GetName()</span><br/>
<span>@Model.Customer.Landine</span><br/>
<span>Ticket Id: @Model.Id</span>
</div>
<div>
@foreach (var repair in Model.Repairs)
{ 
    <div style="border-bottom: black">
        <span>@repair.RepairType.Name</span><br />
     <span> Repair Status: <span class="status">@(repair.IsDone ? "Done" : "Processing")</span></span>
        @if (!repair.IsDone)
        {
            <span><input type="checkbox" class="status-checkbox" data-repair-
            id="@repair.Id" />Mark as done</span><br />
        }

        <span>Location: @Model.Location.Name</span>
    </div>

}
</div>
```

and here is my jQuery..

```
@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('span .status-checkbox').on("click",
            function () {

                var checkBox = $("span .status-checkbox");
                var status = checkBox.is(":checked");
                var data = {
                    id: checkBox.attr("data-repair-id"),
                    isChecked: status

                };
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Repairs/UpdateStatus',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("span .status").html(data);
                        checkBox.hide();
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("Problem updating repair status");
                    }
                });

            });
    });
</script>
}
```

and here is the controller code..

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateStatus(int id, bool isChecked)
     {
        var repair = await _context.Repairs.FindAsync(id);
        if (repair != null)
        {
            repair.IsDone = isChecked;
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Content("Done");

     }
```

Comment: I think issue is in this  `var checkBox = $("span .status-checkbox");` line. Change to  `var checkBox = $(this);`

Comment: Check if `@repair.Id` is passed correctly. I think its value is always same. Debug and check in chrome.

Comment: `Model.Repairs` is a collection, so I suspected only first value iterated in `foreach` loop after passing to view. Check both `Id` & `IsDone` property which controls visibility of corresponding checkbox.

Comment: @User3250 your solution solved the server side and the checkboxes don't all fade. Just one little thing when the text of one is marked as status:done all of them are marked done even if on server side only 1 is saved as done. i suspect that when i update the html of $(span .status) I am not doing it correctly. can you come up with solution for this please?

Comment: @abe you are right. Pls check my answer below. Let me know if any issues with it. As I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you view to add id props to like below:

```
@foreach (var repair in Model.Repairs)
{ 
    <div style="border-bottom: black">
    <span>@repair.RepairType.Name</span><br />
   <span> Repair Status: <span id="sp_@repair.Id" class="status">@(repair.IsDone ? "Done" : "Processing")</span></span>
    @if (!repair.IsDone)
    {
        <span><input type="checkbox" class="status-checkbox" data-repair-
        id="@repair.Id" />Mark as done</span><br />
    }

    <span>Location: @Model.Location.Name</span>
  </div>

}
```

And then in your script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span .status-checkbox').on("click",
        function () {

            var checkBox = $(this);
            var status = checkBox.is(":checked");
            var repairId = checkbox.data('repair-id');
            var data = {
                id: checkBox.attr("data-repair-id"),
                isChecked: status

            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Repairs/UpdateStatus',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#sp_"+repairId).html(data);
                    checkBox.hide();
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("Problem updating repair status");
                }
            });

        });
});
</script>
}
```

I haven't tested it so you might need to make few changes as needed.

Comment: for some reason when i updated the code nothing happens at all

Comment: @abe Pls check my latest edit. Change here `<span id="sp_@repair.Id"`

Comment: server side works also the checkbox gets hidden but status doesn't get updated. it seems like somehow the id is not getting dynamically generated

Comment: You mean you can't find the span using id? Can you check source if you get that id generated for the span?

Comment: how can  check that

Comment: Right click on browser. Click view source. Search for "sp_" in view source page.

Comment: got it i mistakenly wrote sp@repair.id and now i wrote sp_@repair.id and its working thanks

Comment: Happy to help! Finding items by Id is always easier and faster so always consider generating unique ids for elements you want to manipulate in jquery.